# TG Pro and Powermetrics

Tags: activity-monitor

Recently I discovered an app called `TG Pro` that has all information about the CPU and GPU temperature. However, it shows that it is on sale with $10.00. But I'm not sure if this payment is monthly or one-time. As a medium computer user, should I buy the application? I heard that a built-in terminal also provides similar information with `powermetrics`, but is it available in M1 based Macs? If so, what command can I use to see all the information?

Comment: From the developers page on [TG Pro](https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/tgpro/) I can't see anything that suggests you need to make a monthly payment. Write the developer Tunabelly (mailto:support@tunabelly.com) for more information.

Comment: @IconDaemon Do you know the terminal command for powermetrics on M1 based Macs?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea - I don't own a M1 device (yet.)

Comment: @IconDaemon Can you tell me the command for intel-based Macs? I can try that on my M1 device.

Comment: I've never executed the powermetrics command, but if you want to find out all the details, type `man powermetrics` in a Terminal window. [This page](https://srdbranding.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-power-metrics-for-mac-os-x-9a678b48607e) may be of some use.

Comment: Thanks! I got it with `sudo powermetrics`